# Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations in NestJs with Yarn 3

Tags: typescript, nestjs, yarn-v3

I created a NestJs app like this:
`nest new .`
The files were generated and run:
`yarn`
to install all dependecines.
Then run:
`yarn start:dev`
And here is the error:

```
src/app.controller.ts:1:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app.module.ts:1:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app.service.ts:1:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/main.ts:1:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
```

Yarn version: 3.2.2
Node version: 16.16.0
Nest version: 9.1.2

Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Make sure that you got `node_modules` before `yarn start:dev`
Also, you could run `yarn why @nestjs/core` to see if that package was installed

Comment: I have run `yarn why @nestjs/core` and this is the result: `nest-app@workspace: @nestjs/core@npm:9.0.11 [7c667] (via npm:^9.0.0 [7c667])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue with VSCode I navigated to the root of my project in the terminal and entered the following two commands:

`yarn add eslint`

`yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

If you are using a different IDE, then check out yarn's documentation for setting up pnp for that IDE at https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

Comment: i had the exact same problem, tried the exact same thing, but it still didn't resolve the error :(

Comment: The officials docs actually warn you about needing to use Plug'n'Plays install: https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp